# print $1 =~ s/-// in perl

Tags: regex, perl

This results in the error "Modification of a read-only value attempted at..."

```
$mfgs = "AUDBMWCH-FO-TOY";
while( $mfgs =~ /(.{3})/g ) {
    print $1 =~ s/-// . "\n";
}
```

How do I do this without adding additional lines? As far I can tell Perl doesn't have a built-in `str_replace()` function. I could just write one, but as I said, I'm trying to figure out how to do this without additional lines of code.

**This is not being used in a real project. This is only being used for learning purposes.**

Comment: Can you explain your constraint about not wanting add another line of code? This is obviously trivial to solve if you don't have such a constraint.

Comment: @GregHewgill, No constraint really. Just learning Perl and from what I've seen so far, it just seems like there has to be a simple way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print( do { ( my $x = $1 ) =~ s/-//; $x }, "\n" );
print( ( apply { s/-// } $1 ), "\n" );
say( do { ( my $x = $1 ) =~ s/-//; $x } );  # 5.10+
say( apply { s/-// } $1 );                  # 5.10+
say( $x =~ s/-//r );                        # 5.14+
```

`apply` comes from [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?List%3a%3aMoreUtils).

Comment: @druciferre, The `do` allows multiple statements, not the declaration of `$x`. The latter could be done without `do`.

Answer (score 6):

### Let's take a step back

```
$mfgs = "AUDBMWCH-FO-TOY";
while( $mfgs =~ /(.{3})/g ) {
    print $1 =~ s/-// . "\n";
}
```

is simply reading the `$mfgs` string three characters at a time and removing hyphens.

One could re-write this as the following:

```
say for map { s|-||r }  $mfgs =~ /.../g ; # Works in Perl 5.14+

use List::MoreUtils 'apply';
say for apply { s|-|| } $mfgs =~ /.../g ; # If that 'r' flag isn't there
```

or use the transliteration operator ([`tr///`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)) seeing there is nothing inherently regexy going on:

```
say for map tr!-!!dr , $mfgs =~ /.../g ;
```

Both ways would give identical results if there is only up to one hyphen in a block of three characters. This is because `tr/-//dr` would remove all hyphens, and `s/-//r` removes only the first occurrence.

---

That answers how one could do it otherwise, so let's see why it wasn't working before

### Why can't `$1` be modified?

According to [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) (emphasis added):

> **`$<digits> ($1, $2, ...)`**
>
> Contains the subpattern from the corresponding set of capturing
>   parentheses from the last successful pattern match, not counting
>   patterns matched in nested blocks that have been exited already.
>
> These variables are ***read-only*** and dynamically-scoped.

In other words, `$1` can't be modified, which is what the `s///` was trying to do.

However, a copy of `$1` *can* be modified, which is somewhat covered in [Jonathan Leffler's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8692085/133939).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you'd want to do that - the data structure is sub-optimal compared with:

```
my @mfgs = ( "AUD", "BMW", "CH", "FO", "TOY" );
```

However, this works:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my($mfgs, $x) = ("AUDBMWCH-FO-TOY");
while ($mfgs =~ /(.{3})/g)
{
    printf "%s\n", ($x = $1, $x =~ s/-//, $x);  
}
```

If you do without strictures or warnings, you can use:

```
my $mfgs = "AUDBMWCH-FO-TOY";
while ($mfgs =~ /(.{3})/g)
{
    printf "%s\n", ($x = $1, $x =~ s/-//, $x);
}
```

However, it is better not even to bother learning how you can (ab)use Perl without `use strict;` and `use warnings;` (or `use diagnostics;`) in effect.

Comment: Your third block of code is the best I've seen so far. If it worked when using `use strict;` then it'd be exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: While juggling `$x` around inside a `printf` list is cute, it looks rather hazardous and illegible, and is not more efficient than simply doing `my $x = $1; $x =~ s/-//g; say $x;`.

Comment: I make no claims of any sort for good style; it is abominable style.  It does achieve what the questioner wanted to achieve, and that is its only defense.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Granted. However, it might be a good idea to make note of how and why it is not good style, and then provide a solution that is.

Answer (score 3):

In Perl 5.14, there is a new `/r` modifier available for `s///` substitutions (as well as `tr///`/`y///` transliterations), which causes the returned result to be a new string, not changing the original.

```
use 5.014;

$mfgs = "AUDBMWCH-FO-TOY";
while ($mfgs =~ /(.{3})/g) {
    say $1 =~ s/-//r;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I do this without adding additional lines? As far I can tell
>   Perl doesn't have a built-in str_replace() function. I could just
>   write one, but as I said, I'm trying to figure out how to do this
>   without additional lines of code.

Did you read [perlfunc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html)? Also, this is not about functions, it's about `$1` being a read-only variable. See [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Variables-related-to-regular-expressions).

```
$<digits> ($1, $2, ...)
```

> Contains the subpattern from the corresponding set of capturing
>   parentheses from the last successful pattern match, not counting
>   patterns matched in nested blocks that have been exited already.
>
> These variables are read-only and dynamically-scoped.

---

As near as I can tell, this is the most economic way to achieve the code in question:

```
tr/-//d, say for $mfgs =~ /.{3}/g;
```

Or the long version:

```
my $mfgs = "AUDBMWCH-FO-TOY";
for my $str ($mfgs =~ /.{3}/g) {
    $str =~ tr/-//d;
    say $str;
}
```

Note that capturing parentheses are not required in this case. From [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Matching-in-list-context):

> The /g modifier specifies global pattern matching--that is, matching
>   as many times as possible within the string. How it behaves depends on
>   the context. In list context, it returns a list of the substrings
>   matched by any capturing parentheses in the regular expression. If
>   there are no parentheses, it returns a list of all the matched
>   strings, as if there were parentheses around the whole pattern.

Also note the difference between `while` and `for (foreach)`. `while` will iterate over the matches as they appear (using `/g` in scalar context), with implicit use of the `\G` assertion, but it will not store the match in a variable (except `$1`). `for` will extract all the matches at once (using `/g` in list context), and the match will be aliased in the loop variable (`$_` in the first case, `my $str` in the second).

> In scalar context, each execution of m//g finds the next match,
>   returning true if it matches, and false if there is no further match.
>   The position after the last match can be read or set using the pos()
>   function; see pos. A failed match normally resets the search position
>   to the beginning of the string, but you can avoid that by adding the
>   /c modifier (e.g. m//gc). Modifying the target string also resets the
>   search position.

Comment: Unfortunately `split` doesn't return the same array as `$mfgr =~ /.../g`. It returns `("", "AUD", "", "BMW", "", "CH-", "", "FO-", "", "TOY")`

Comment: @Zaid You're right. Not sure what I was thinking there. Day after new years eve.

Answer (score 0):

You could always just do this to get an array of items split by your delimiter..

```
@a = split("-", $mfgs);
```

To str_replace you use

```
$var =~ s/search/replace/g;
```

Like so

```
$mfgs =~ s/-/\n/g;
printf("%s\n", $mfgs);
```

Comment: there is no delimiter in this example, every three characters is what is being used. this is not being used a functional piece of code, it is being used for learning purposes only.